# Missing expression Error with Insert Select query in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, intellij-idea, oracle-sqldeveloper

i got this error with Oracle SQL with Insert Select query and don't where the error comes from
the SQL Query is:

```
insert into GroupScenarioAction (ID, ID_UUID, GPSCENARIO_UUID, ACTION, VERSION)
(select DEFAULT , '0', ACTION.ID_UUID, '5310AFAA......', '1', ACTION_ID, '0'
from ACTION where ACTION.id not in (select ACTION FROM GroupScenarioAction where 
GPSCENARIO = '1'));
```

the error is ORA-00936: missing expression Position 129

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Typically, it's `INSERT .... SELECT ...;`  not `INSERT ... (SELECT ...);`

Comment: i tried that @JonArmstrong

Comment: Count the number of columns in the insert column list and the number of values in the SELECT list.... in your question, that is.  Not your picture.  Provide the `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: While your posted question has typos / errors, I think the issue is your use of `DEFAULT`.  Instead of using `DEFAULT`, just remove that column from the insert list and remove the `DEFAULT` term from the select list, like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=79675858266156063f213f3c82e0840b

Comment: i cant copy paste the codes, they are on another machine and i use vm for coding. but i add some pictures for more details.
@jonArmstrong

Comment: The images aren't helpful.  Use text.  Did you check the fiddle?  It corrects the basic issue.  You had other mistakes I had to remove too.  So the SQL probably isn't usable exactly as is.  It's much easier if you can post the `CREATE TABLE` statements (as text) necessary to support the INSERT statement.  Keep the test case simple.

Comment: removing the "ID" and the DEFAULT return the "ORA-01400: Cannot insert null into (MARKAZDARMANIDB"."GOROOHSCENARIOACTION"."ID") @JonArmstrong

Comment: What `DEFAULT` are you referring to?  That's why having the `CREATE TABLE` statements (in text) are really necessary to review the issue.

Comment: the DEFAULT referring to ID (Auto Increment, Not NULL, PK)  field in GOROOHSCENAROACTION table. let me ask the boss for permission about sending CREATE TABLE statement in text (will take hours).
table image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvmBy.png

Comment: Use `null` instead of `default`. Is there some other default that you're expecting?

Comment: will not help, take back error: ORA-01400: Cannon insert null into (MARKAZDARMANIDB"."GOROOHSCENARIOACTION"."ID") i used DEFAULT just for add new records for ID in GOROOHSCENARIOACTION
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvmBy.png
 @shawnt00

Comment: Please, provide [minimal **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I'm absolutely sure you will find the issue when you try to make it minimal. Currently you specify 5 target columns and 7 source columns, and Oracle should say `too many values`. As it doesn't currently see this issue, the error is most likely about `default` as mentioned in other comments, because it is reserved keyword

Comment: I thought it was nullable but apparently I looked at the wrong column. It's the primary key so where are those values supposed to come from?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to assist because

- you posted relevant data as **images** (why do you expect us to type all of that so that we could try it?) instead of **code** (which can easily be copy/pasted and used afterwards)
- code you posted (the `insert` statement itself) uses columns that don't exist in any tables whose description you posted

  - for example, `insert` inserts into `GroupScenarioAction`, but there's no such table there; maybe it is `goroohscenarioaction`? Or, there's no `action_id` column in the `action` table
- you're inserting values into **5** columns, but `select` statement contains **7** columns; that raises `ORA-00913: too many values` error, you don't even come to the *missing expression* error

Shortly, as if you tried to do everyhing you could to prevent us from helping you.

---

One of comments you posted says

> It's the primary key so where are those values supposed to come from?

That's the `default` keyword in

```
insert into GroupScenarioAction (ID, ...)
   (select DEFAULT, ...
           -------
           this
```

Looks like the `ID` column is created as an identity column whose value is autogenerated (i.e. Oracle takes care about it), which also means that you're on Oracle 12c or above (there was no such an option in lower versions). On the other hand `create table goroohscenarioaction` statement doesn't suggest anything like that.

---

Anyway: if you do it *right*, it works. I created two sample tables with a minimum column set, just to make `insert` work. Also, as I'm on 11gXE (which doesn't support identity columns, I'm inserting a sequence value which is, basically, what identity column uses *in the background* anyway):

```
SQL> create table groupscenarioaction
  2    (id              number,
  3     id_uuid         raw(255),
  4     gpscenario_uuid raw(255),
  5     action          number,
  6     version         number
  7    );

Table created.

SQL> create table action
  2    (id_uuid  raw(255),
  3     id       number
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seq;

Sequence created.
```

Insert you posted; I commented out columns that either don't exist or are superfluous. It *works*; though, didn't insert anything as my table(s) are empty, but it doesn't raise any error:

```
SQL> insert into GroupScenarioAction
  2    (ID, ID_UUID, GPSCENARIO_UUID, ACTION, VERSION)
  3    (select 1 /*DEFAULT*/ , '0', ACTION.ID_UUID, '5310AFAA......', '1' --, id /*ACTION_ID*/, '0'
  4     from ACTION
  5     where ACTION.id not in (select ACTION FROM GroupScenarioAction
  6                             where  gpscenario_uuid/*GPSCENARIO*/ = '1'));

0 rows created.
```

Beautified:

```
SQL> insert into groupscenarioaction
  2    (id, id_uuid, gpscenario_uuid, action, version)
  3    (select seq.nextval, '0', a.id_uuid, '5310AFAA......', '1'
  4     from action a
  5     where a.id not in (select g.action
  6                        from groupscenarioaction g
  7                        where g.gpscenario_uuid = '1'));

0 rows created.

SQL>
```

---

Now that you know a little bit more about what's bothering use to help you, and if what I wrote isn't enough, consider editing the original question you posted (simply remove everything that's wrong and write something that is true and we can use).

Comment: I appreciate  for writing down the codes. i will edit this post asap